# How to encrypt the pyspark dataframe column value in Glue Spark job?

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

Can you please help me here to tell How can be encrypted the pyspark dataframe column value in Glue Spark job?
I've tried with pycrypto but Glue spark job doesn't support that.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I need to encrypt some pyspark Data Frame columns using AWS Glue SparkJobs? I've tried to use Cryptography Fernet and PyCrypto python packages but here problem is, Fernet and Pycrypto implementation is based on C++ hence it's not supported by AWS glue